# CodeIgniter Unable to connect to database

Tags: codeigniter

when i open CodeIgniter project than it can display not able to connect to database

**Error message** 
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter-Standard-Project-master\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 76

DB_driver.php

```
            <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class CI_DB_driver {

        var $username       = 'root';
        var $password       = '';
        var $hostname       = 'localhost';
        var $database       = 'groups';
        var $dbdriver       = 'mysql';
        var $dbprefix       = '';
        var $char_set       = 'utf8';
        var $dbcollat       = 'utf8_general_ci';
        var $autoinit       = TRUE; // Whether to automatically initialize the DB
        var $swap_pre       = '';
        var $port           = '';
        var $pconnect       = true;
        var $conn_id        = FALSE;
        var $result_id      = FALSE;
        var $db_debug       = true;
        var $benchmark      = 0;
        var $query_count    = 0;
        var $bind_marker    = '?';
        var $save_queries   = TRUE;
        var $queries        = array();
        var $query_times    = array();
        var $data_cache     = array();
        var $trans_enabled  = TRUE;
        var $trans_strict   = TRUE;
        var $_trans_depth   = 0;
        var $_trans_status  = TRUE; // Used with transactions to determine if a rollback should occur
        var $cache_on       = FALSE;
        var $cachedir       = '';
        var $cache_autodel  = FALSE;
        var $CACHE; // The cache class object

        var $_protect_identifiers   = TRUE;
        var $_reserved_identifiers  = array('*'); // Identifiers that should NOT be escaped

        // These are use with Oracle
        var $stmt_id;
        var $curs_id;
        var $limit_used;



        function __construct($params)
        {
            if (is_array($params))
            {
                foreach ($params as $key => $val)
                {
                    $this->$key = $val;
                }
            }

            log_message('debug', 'Database Driver Class Initialized');
        }
        function initialize()
        {
            // If an existing connection resource is available
            // there is no need to connect and select the database
            if (is_resource($this->conn_id) OR is_object($this->conn_id))
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
    $this->conn_id = ($this->pconnect == FALSE) ? $this->db_connect() : $this->db_pconnect();

            // No connection resource?  Throw an error
            if ( ! $this->conn_id)
            {
                log_message('error', 'Unable to connect to the database');

                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    $this->display_error('db_unable_to_connect');
                }
                return FALSE;
            }

            // ----------------------------------------------------------------

            // Select the DB... assuming a database name is specified in the config file
            if ($this->database != '')
            {
                if ( ! $this->db_select())
                {
                    log_message('error', 'Unable to select database: '.$this->database);

                    if ($this->db_debug)
                    {
                        $this->display_error('db_unable_to_select', $this->database);
                    }
                    return FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                    // We've selected the DB. Now we set the character set
                    if ( ! $this->db_set_charset($this->char_set, $this->dbcollat))
                    {
                        return FALSE;
                    }

                    return TRUE;
                }
            }

            return TRUE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        function db_set_charset($charset, $collation)
        {
            if ( ! $this->_db_set_charset($this->char_set, $this->dbcollat))
            {
                log_message('error', 'Unable to set database connection charset: '.$this->char_set);

                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    $this->display_error('db_unable_to_set_charset', $this->char_set);
                }

                return FALSE;
            }

            return TRUE;
        }

        function platform()
        {
            return $this->dbdriver;
        }

        function version()
        {
            if (FALSE === ($sql = $this->_version()))
            {
                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    return $this->display_error('db_unsupported_function');
                }
                return FALSE;
            }
            $driver_version_exceptions = array('oci8', 'sqlite', 'cubrid');

            if (in_array($this->dbdriver, $driver_version_exceptions))
            {
                return $sql;
            }
            else
            {
                $query = $this->query($sql);
                return $query->row('ver');
            }
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        function query($sql, $binds = FALSE, $return_object = TRUE)
        {
            if ($sql == '')
            {
                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    log_message('error', 'Invalid query: '.$sql);
                    return $this->display_error('db_invalid_query');
                }
                return FALSE;
            }

            // Verify table prefix and replace if necessary
            if ( ($this->dbprefix != '' AND $this->swap_pre != '') AND ($this->dbprefix != $this->swap_pre) )
            {
                $sql = preg_replace("/(\W)".$this->swap_pre."(\S+?)/", "\\1".$this->dbprefix."\\2", $sql);
            }
            if ($this->cache_on == TRUE AND stristr($sql, 'SELECT'))
            {
                if ($this->_cache_init())
                {
                    $this->load_rdriver();
                    if (FALSE !== ($cache = $this->CACHE->read($sql)))
                    {
                        return $cache;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Compile binds if needed
            if ($binds !== FALSE)
            {
                $sql = $this->compile_binds($sql, $binds);
            }

            // Save the  query for debugging
            if ($this->save_queries == TRUE)
            {
                $this->queries[] = $sql;
            }

            // Start the Query Timer
            $time_start = list($sm, $ss) = explode(' ', microtime());

            // Run the Query
            if (FALSE === ($this->result_id = $this->simple_query($sql)))
            {
                if ($this->save_queries == TRUE)
                {
                    $this->query_times[] = 0;
                }

                // This will trigger a rollback if transactions are being used
                $this->_trans_status = FALSE;

                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    // grab the error number and message now, as we might run some
                    // additional queries before displaying the error
                    $error_no = $this->_error_number();
                    $error_msg = $this->_error_message();

                    // We call this function in order to roll-back queries
                    // if transactions are enabled.  If we don't call this here
                    // the error message will trigger an exit, causing the
                    // transactions to remain in limbo.
                    $this->trans_complete();

                    // Log and display errors
                    log_message('error', 'Query error: '.$error_msg);
                    return $this->display_error(
                                            array(
                                                    'Error Number: '.$error_no,
                                                    $error_msg,
                                                    $sql
                                                )
                                            );
                }

                return FALSE;
            }

            // Stop and aggregate the query time results
            $time_end = list($em, $es) = explode(' ', microtime());
            $this->benchmark += ($em + $es) - ($sm + $ss);

            if ($this->save_queries == TRUE)
            {
                $this->query_times[] = ($em + $es) - ($sm + $ss);
            }

            // Increment the query counter
            $this->query_count++;

            // Was the query a "write" type?
            // If so we'll simply return true
            if ($this->is_write_type($sql) === TRUE)
            {
                // If caching is enabled we'll auto-cleanup any
                // existing files related to this particular URI
                if ($this->cache_on == TRUE AND $this->cache_autodel == TRUE AND $this->_cache_init())
                {
                    $this->CACHE->delete();
                }

                return TRUE;
            }

            // Return TRUE if we don't need to create a result object
            // Currently only the Oracle driver uses this when stored
            // procedures are used
            if ($return_object !== TRUE)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }

            // Load and instantiate the result driver

            $driver         = $this->load_rdriver();
            $RES            = new $driver();
            $RES->conn_id   = $this->conn_id;
            $RES->result_id = $this->result_id;

            if ($this->dbdriver == 'oci8')
            {
                $RES->stmt_id       = $this->stmt_id;
                $RES->curs_id       = NULL;
                $RES->limit_used    = $this->limit_used;
                $this->stmt_id      = FALSE;
            }

            // oci8 vars must be set before calling this
            $RES->num_rows  = $RES->num_rows();

            // Is query caching enabled?  If so, we'll serialize the
            // result object and save it to a cache file.
            if ($this->cache_on == TRUE AND $this->_cache_init())
            {
                $CR = new CI_DB_result();
                $CR->num_rows       = $RES->num_rows();
                $CR->result_object  = $RES->result_object();
                $CR->result_array   = $RES->result_array();

                // Reset these since cached objects can not utilize resource IDs.
                $CR->conn_id        = NULL;
                $CR->result_id      = NULL;

                $this->CACHE->write($sql, $CR);
            }

            return $RES;
        }
        function load_rdriver()
        {
            $driver = 'CI_DB_'.$this->dbdriver.'_result';

            if ( ! class_exists($driver))
            {
                include_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB_result.php');
                include_once(BASEPATH.'database/drivers/'.$this->dbdriver.'/'.$this->dbdriver.'_result.php');
            }

            return $driver;
        }

        function simple_query($sql)
        {
            if ( ! $this->conn_id)
            {
                $this->initialize();
            }

            return $this->_execute($sql);
        }
        function trans_off()
        {
            $this->trans_enabled = FALSE;
        }
        function trans_strict($mode = TRUE)
        {
            $this->trans_strict = is_bool($mode) ? $mode : TRUE;
        }
        function trans_start($test_mode = FALSE)
        {
            if ( ! $this->trans_enabled)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            // When transactions are nested we only begin/commit/rollback the outermost ones
            if ($this->_trans_depth > 0)
            {
                $this->_trans_depth += 1;
                return;
            }

            $this->trans_begin($test_mode);
        }
        function trans_complete()
        {
            if ( ! $this->trans_enabled)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            // When transactions are nested we only begin/commit/rollback the outermost ones
            if ($this->_trans_depth > 1)
            {
                $this->_trans_depth -= 1;
                return TRUE;
            }

            // The query() function will set this flag to FALSE in the event that a query failed
            if ($this->_trans_status === FALSE)
            {
                $this->trans_rollback();

                // If we are NOT running in strict mode, we will reset
                // the _trans_status flag so that subsequent groups of transactions
                // will be permitted.
                if ($this->trans_strict === FALSE)
                {
                    $this->_trans_status = TRUE;
                }

                log_message('debug', 'DB Transaction Failure');
                return FALSE;
            }

            $this->trans_commit();
            return TRUE;
        }


        function trans_status()
        {
            return $this->_trans_status;
        }


        function compile_binds($sql, $binds)
        {
            if (strpos($sql, $this->bind_marker) === FALSE)
            {
                return $sql;
            }

            if ( ! is_array($binds))
            {
                $binds = array($binds);
            }

            // Get the sql segments around the bind markers
            $segments = explode($this->bind_marker, $sql);

            // The count of bind should be 1 less then the count of segments
            // If there are more bind arguments trim it down
            if (count($binds) >= count($segments)) {
                $binds = array_slice($binds, 0, count($segments)-1);
            }

            // Construct the binded query
            $result = $segments[0];
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($binds as $bind)
            {
                $result .= $this->escape($bind);
                $result .= $segments[++$i];
            }

            return $result;
        }

        function is_write_type($sql)
        {
            if ( ! preg_match('/^\s*"?(SET|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|REPLACE|CREATE|DROP|TRUNCATE|LOAD DATA|COPY|ALTER|GRANT|REVOKE|LOCK|UNLOCK)\s+/i', $sql))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
            return TRUE;
        }

        function elapsed_time($decimals = 6)
        {
            return number_format($this->benchmark, $decimals);
        }

        function total_queries()
        {
            return $this->query_count;
        }

        function last_query()
        {
            return end($this->queries);
        }


        function escape($str)
        {
            if (is_string($str))
            {
                $str = "'".$this->escape_str($str)."'";
            }
            elseif (is_bool($str))
            {
                $str = ($str === FALSE) ? 0 : 1;
            }
            elseif (is_null($str))
            {
                $str = 'NULL';
            }

            return $str;
        }


        function escape_like_str($str)
        {
            return $this->escape_str($str, TRUE);
        }


        function primary($table = '')
        {
            $fields = $this->list_fields($table);

            if ( ! is_array($fields))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            return current($fields);
        }

        function list_tables($constrain_by_prefix = FALSE)
        {
            // Is there a cached result?
            if (isset($this->data_cache['table_names']))
            {
                return $this->data_cache['table_names'];
            }

            if (FALSE === ($sql = $this->_list_tables($constrain_by_prefix)))
            {
                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    return $this->display_error('db_unsupported_function');
                }
                return FALSE;
            }

            $retval = array();
            $query = $this->query($sql);

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
                {
                    if (isset($row['TABLE_NAME']))
                    {
                        $retval[] = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $retval[] = array_shift($row);
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->data_cache['table_names'] = $retval;
            return $this->data_cache['table_names'];
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Determine if a particular table exists
         * @access  public
         * @return  boolean
         */
        function table_exists($table_name)
        {
            return ( ! in_array($this->_protect_identifiers($table_name, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), $this->list_tables())) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Fetch MySQL Field Names
         *
         * @access  public
         * @param   string  the table name
         * @return  array
         */
        function list_fields($table = '')
        {
            // Is there a cached result?
            if (isset($this->data_cache['field_names'][$table]))
            {
                return $this->data_cache['field_names'][$table];
            }

            if ($table == '')
            {
                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    return $this->display_error('db_field_param_missing');
                }
                return FALSE;
            }

            if (FALSE === ($sql = $this->_list_columns($table)))
            {
                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    return $this->display_error('db_unsupported_function');
                }
                return FALSE;
            }

            $query = $this->query($sql);

            $retval = array();
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                if (isset($row['COLUMN_NAME']))
                {
                    $retval[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
                }
                else
                {
                    $retval[] = current($row);
                }
            }

            $this->data_cache['field_names'][$table] = $retval;
            return $this->data_cache['field_names'][$table];
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Determine if a particular field exists
         * @access  public
         * @param   string
         * @param   string
         * @return  boolean
         */
        function field_exists($field_name, $table_name)
        {
            return ( ! in_array($field_name, $this->list_fields($table_name))) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Returns an object with field data
         *
         * @access  public
         * @param   string  the table name
         * @return  object
         */
        function field_data($table = '')
        {
            if ($table == '')
            {
                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    return $this->display_error('db_field_param_missing');
                }
                return FALSE;
            }

            $query = $this->query($this->_field_data($this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE)));

            return $query->field_data();
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Generate an insert string
         *
         * @access  public
         * @param   string  the table upon which the query will be performed
         * @param   array   an associative array data of key/values
         * @return  string
         */
        function insert_string($table, $data)
        {
            $fields = array();
            $values = array();

            foreach ($data as $key => $val)
            {
                $fields[] = $this->_escape_identifiers($key);
                $values[] = $this->escape($val);
            }

            return $this->_insert($this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), $fields, $values);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Generate an update string
         *
         * @access  public
         * @param   string  the table upon which the query will be performed
         * @param   array   an associative array data of key/values
         * @param   mixed   the "where" statement
         * @return  string
         */
        function update_string($table, $data, $where)
        {
            if ($where == '')
            {
                return false;
            }

            $fields = array();
            foreach ($data as $key => $val)
            {
                $fields[$this->_protect_identifiers($key)] = $this->escape($val);
            }

            if ( ! is_array($where))
            {
                $dest = array($where);
            }
            else
            {
                $dest = array();
                foreach ($where as $key => $val)
                {
                    $prefix = (count($dest) == 0) ? '' : ' AND ';

                    if ($val !== '')
                    {
                        if ( ! $this->_has_operator($key))
                        {
                            $key .= ' =';
                        }

                        $val = ' '.$this->escape($val);
                    }

                    $dest[] = $prefix.$key.$val;
                }
            }

            return $this->_update($this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), $fields, $dest);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Tests whether the string has an SQL operator
         *
         * @access  private
         * @param   string
         * @return  bool
         */
        function _has_operator($str)
        {
            $str = trim($str);
            if ( ! preg_match("/(\s|<|>|!|=|is null|is not null)/i", $str))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            return TRUE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Enables a native PHP function to be run, using a platform agnostic wrapper.
         *
         * @access  public
         * @param   string  the function name
         * @param   mixed   any parameters needed by the function
         * @return  mixed
         */
        function call_function($function)
        {
            $driver = ($this->dbdriver == 'postgre') ? 'pg_' : $this->dbdriver.'_';

            if (FALSE === strpos($driver, $function))
            {
                $function = $driver.$function;
            }

            if ( ! function_exists($function))
            {
                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    return $this->display_error('db_unsupported_function');
                }
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                $args = (func_num_args() > 1) ? array_splice(func_get_args(), 1) : null;

                return call_user_func_array($function, $args);
            }
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Set Cache Directory Path
         *
         * @access  public
         * @param   string  the path to the cache directory
         * @return  void
         */
        function cache_set_path($path = '')
        {
            $this->cachedir = $path;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Enable Query Caching
         *
         * @access  public
         * @return  void
         */
        function cache_on()
        {
            $this->cache_on = TRUE;
            return TRUE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Disable Query Caching
         *
         * @access  public
         * @return  void
         */
        function cache_off()
        {
            $this->cache_on = FALSE;
            return FALSE;
        }


        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Delete the cache files associated with a particular URI
         *
         * @access  public
         * @return  void
         */
        function cache_delete($segment_one = '', $segment_two = '')
        {
            if ( ! $this->_cache_init())
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
            return $this->CACHE->delete($segment_one, $segment_two);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Delete All cache files
         *
         * @access  public
         * @return  void
         */
        function cache_delete_all()
        {
            if ( ! $this->_cache_init())
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            return $this->CACHE->delete_all();
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Initialize the Cache Class
         *
         * @access  private
         * @return  void
         */
        function _cache_init()
        {
            if (is_object($this->CACHE) AND class_exists('CI_DB_Cache'))
            {
                return TRUE;
            }

            if ( ! class_exists('CI_DB_Cache'))
            {
                if ( ! @include(BASEPATH.'database/DB_cache.php'))
                {
                    return $this->cache_off();
                }
            }

            $this->CACHE = new CI_DB_Cache($this); // pass db object to support multiple db connections and returned db objects
            return TRUE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Close DB Connection
         *
         * @access  public
         * @return  void
         */
        function close()
        {
            if (is_resource($this->conn_id) OR is_object($this->conn_id))
            {
                $this->_close($this->conn_id);
            }
            $this->conn_id = FALSE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Display an error message
         *
         * @access  public
         * @param   string  the error message
         * @param   string  any "swap" values
         * @param   boolean whether to localize the message
         * @return  string  sends the application/error_db.php template
         */
        function display_error($error = '', $swap = '', $native = FALSE)
        {
            $LANG =& load_class('Lang', 'core');
            $LANG->load('db');

            $heading = $LANG->line('db_error_heading');

            if ($native == TRUE)
            {
                $message = $error;
            }
            else
            {
                $message = ( ! is_array($error)) ? array(str_replace('%s', $swap, $LANG->line($error))) : $error;
            }

            // Find the most likely culprit of the error by going through
            // the backtrace until the source file is no longer in the
            // database folder.

            $trace = debug_backtrace();

            foreach ($trace as $call)
            {
                if (isset($call['file']) && strpos($call['file'], BASEPATH.'database') === FALSE)
                {
                    // Found it - use a relative path for safety
                    $message[] = 'Filename: '.str_replace(array(BASEPATH, APPPATH), '', $call['file']);
                    $message[] = 'Line Number: '.$call['line'];

                    break;
                }
            }

            $error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
            echo $error->show_error($heading, $message, 'error_db');
            exit;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Protect Identifiers
         *
         * This function adds backticks if appropriate based on db type
         *
         * @access  private
         * @param   mixed   the item to escape
         * @return  mixed   the item with backticks
         */
        function protect_identifiers($item, $prefix_single = FALSE)
        {
            return $this->_protect_identifiers($item, $prefix_single);
        }


        function _protect_identifiers($item, $prefix_single = FALSE, $protect_identifiers = NULL, $field_exists = TRUE)
        {
            if ( ! is_bool($protect_identifiers))
            {
                $protect_identifiers = $this->_protect_identifiers;
            }

            if (is_array($item))
            {
                $escaped_array = array();

                foreach ($item as $k => $v)
                {
                    $escaped_array[$this->_protect_identifiers($k)] = $this->_protect_identifiers($v);
                }

                return $escaped_array;
            }

            // Convert tabs or multiple spaces into single spaces
            $item = preg_replace('/[\t ]+/', ' ', $item);

            // If the item has an alias declaration we remove it and set it aside.
            // Basically we remove everything to the right of the first space
            $alias = '';
            if (strpos($item, ' ') !== FALSE)
            {
                $alias = strstr($item, " ");
                $item = substr($item, 0, - strlen($alias));
            }

            // This is basically a bug fix for queries that use MAX, MIN, etc.
            // If a parenthesis is found we know that we do not need to
            // escape the data or add a prefix.  There's probably a more graceful
            // way to deal with this, but I'm not thinking of it -- Rick
            if (strpos($item, '(') !== FALSE)
            {
                return $item.$alias;
            }

            // Break the string apart if it contains periods, then insert the table prefix
            // in the correct location, assuming the period doesn't indicate that we're dealing
            // with an alias. While we're at it, we will escape the components
            if (strpos($item, '.') !== FALSE)
            {
                $parts  = explode('.', $item);

                // Does the first segment of the exploded item match
                // one of the aliases previously identified?  If so,
                // we have nothing more to do other than escape the item
                if (in_array($parts[0], $this->ar_aliased_tables))
                {
                    if ($protect_identifiers === TRUE)
                    {
                        foreach ($parts as $key => $val)
                        {
                            if ( ! in_array($val, $this->_reserved_identifiers))
                            {
                                $parts[$key] = $this->_escape_identifiers($val);
                            }
                        }

                        $item = implode('.', $parts);
                    }
                    return $item.$alias;
                }

                // Is there a table prefix defined in the config file?  If not, no need to do anything
                if ($this->dbprefix != '')
                {
                    // We now add the table prefix based on some logic.
                    // Do we have 4 segments (hostname.database.table.column)?
                    // If so, we add the table prefix to the column name in the 3rd segment.
                    if (isset($parts[3]))
                    {
                        $i = 2;
                    }
                    // Do we have 3 segments (database.table.column)?
                    // If so, we add the table prefix to the column name in 2nd position
                    elseif (isset($parts[2]))
                    {
                        $i = 1;
                    }
                    // Do we have 2 segments (table.column)?
                    // If so, we add the table prefix to the column name in 1st segment
                    else
                    {
                        $i = 0;
                    }

                    // This flag is set when the supplied $item does not contain a field name.
                    // This can happen when this function is being called from a JOIN.
                    if ($field_exists == FALSE)
                    {
                        $i++;
                    }

                    // Verify table prefix and replace if necessary
                    if ($this->swap_pre != '' && strncmp($parts[$i], $this->swap_pre, strlen($this->swap_pre)) === 0)
                    {
                        $parts[$i] = preg_replace("/^".$this->swap_pre."(\S+?)/", $this->dbprefix."\\1", $parts[$i]);
                    }

                    // We only add the table prefix if it does not already exist
                    if (substr($parts[$i], 0, strlen($this->dbprefix)) != $this->dbprefix)
                    {
                        $parts[$i] = $this->dbprefix.$parts[$i];
                    }

                    // Put the parts back together
                    $item = implode('.', $parts);
                }

                if ($protect_identifiers === TRUE)
                {
                    $item = $this->_escape_identifiers($item);
                }

                return $item.$alias;
            }

            // Is there a table prefix?  If not, no need to insert it
            if ($this->dbprefix != '')
            {
                // Verify table prefix and replace if necessary
                if ($this->swap_pre != '' && strncmp($item, $this->swap_pre, strlen($this->swap_pre)) === 0)
                {
                    $item = preg_replace("/^".$this->swap_pre."(\S+?)/", $this->dbprefix."\\1", $item);
                }

                // Do we prefix an item with no segments?
                if ($prefix_single == TRUE AND substr($item, 0, strlen($this->dbprefix)) != $this->dbprefix)
                {
                    $item = $this->dbprefix.$item;
                }
            }

            if ($protect_identifiers === TRUE AND ! in_array($item, $this->_reserved_identifiers))
            {
                $item = $this->_escape_identifiers($item);
            }

            return $item.$alias;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment @mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, TRUE);
on `system/database/mysql/mysql_driver  in db_connect method delete the @ from @mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, TRUE);`

This will show you the connection error and post result here

PHP 5 or above and CI 3 supports only mysqli

**EDIT**

```
$db['default'] = array( 
'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => DB_HOST, 
 'username' => DB_USER, 
 'password' => DB_PASSWORD, 
 'database' => DB_NAME, 
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

[Refer](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html)
Edit: application/database/config.php

Comment: pleace give ne answer

Comment: is your MySQL Server running ??

Comment: whats your CI version ??

Comment: sorry i dont know

Comment: try changing DB driver to mysqli cI 3 or above supports mysqli I have updated my answer along with the documentation reference please check it

Comment: DO NOT go altering system files. If you bothered to read the Codeigniter user guide it shows how to set up the database connection using application/config/database.php as @DanishAli has mentioned above.

Comment: @JadavRamesh Please edit application/config/database.php as Tim commented i forgot you posted DB_driver.php

Comment: @SanuKhan While you are at it, you might want to remove that 1st paragraph in your answer as well. It's referring to altering a system file too.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I have updated my answer thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2):

If you have wampp server use this configuration.
If you have xampp use htdocx instead of www

C/wampp/www/Your-project-folder/application/config/database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';

$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => DB_HOST,
'username' => DB_USER,
'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
'database' => DB_NAME,
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```